# Kendo MVC Wrappers client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, data-annotations, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I'm using the Kendo UI Server Side Wrappers to create a grid to manage (CRUD) a list of messages in our system.  The model is very simple and it only requires that the message is 150 characters or less.  To enforce the message length I'm using the following data annotation in my model:

```
[StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Message exceeded the maximum length allowed.  Please ensure you message is no longer than 150 characters")]
```

Here's what my grid looks like:

```
@model OperatorMessageListModel

@{
    TransactionStatusType status = Model.TransactionStatus;
    ViewBag.Title = String.Format("{0} Transaction Operator Messages", status);
    string header = string.Format("{0} Transaction Messages", status);
    string messagesTableId = string.Format("{0}TransactionOperatorMessagesGrid", status);
}

<h2>@header</h2>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.OperatorMessages)
      .Name(messagesTableId)
      .TableHtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 50% height:75%" })
      .Columns(columns =>
                   {

                       columns.Bound(m => m.Message).Title("");
                       columns.Bound(m => m.Index).Hidden(true);
                       if (!Model.IsInherited) //only edit if you own the list and there's anyhting to edit
                       {
                           columns.Command(cmd =>
                                               {
                                                   cmd.Edit().UpdateText("Save");
                                                   cmd.Destroy();
                                               }).Width("20%");

                       }
                   })
     .Pageable()
     .Scrollable(s => s.Enabled(false))
     .ToolBar(cmd =>
                  {

                      if (!Model.IsInherited) //you can add messages to the lists that you own
                      {
                          cmd.Create().Text("Add new message");
                      }

                      if (!Model.OwnedByRoot && Model.OperatorMessages.Any()) //if the root owns this it can't override or inherit its own list.
                      {
                          var actionName = Model.IsInherited ? "OverrideTrasactionMessageList" : "InheritTrasactionMessageList";
                          cmd.Custom().Text(Model.OverrideOrInheritButtonText).Action(actionName, "OperatorMessage", new { Model.OrgId, Model.TransactionStatus });
                      }
                  }
           )

     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
     .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Server()
        .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.Index))
        .Create(c => c.Action("CreateTransactionMessage", "OperatorMessage", new { @Model.OrgId, @Model.TransactionStatus }))
        .Read(c => c.Action("List", "OperatorMessage", new { @Model.OrgId, @Model.TransactionStatus }))
        .Update(c => c.Action("EditTransactionMessage", "OperatorMessage"))
        .Destroy(c => c.Action("DeleteTrasactionMessage", "OperatorMessage"))

     )
)
```

Here's the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTransactionMessage([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request,
                                                 OperatorMessageModel newMessage, string OrgId,
                                                 string TransactionStatus)
{

    _transactionOperatorMessageService.AddOperatorMessage(OrgId, TransactionStatus, newMessage,
                                                          CurrentUser.Name());
    return RedirectToAction("List", new {OrgId, TransactionStatus});
}
```

When the user enters a message longer than 150 characters, I expect the validation message to be displayed to the user.  Additionally, the form not to be posted back to the controller. Everything works as expcted in Chrome and Firefox.  However, in IE8 the message is displayed but the form is still posted back to the controller.  Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser dev tools?